# how to create bson map based on input

Tags: go, bson, mgo

I am building a bson map in golang using mgo library. I want to refactor some code to be able to avoid duplication.

Consider this:

```
    bson.M {
         "$match" : bson.M{
            "xyz" : "abc",
          },
          "$id_1" : value_1, 
    }
```

and another bson map of type:

```
    bson.M {
         "$match" : bson.M{
            "xyz" : "abc",
          },
          "$id_2" : value_2,
    }
```

How can I combine the two (build bson.M from a function and return, value1/2 are params to this func) to be used based on if value_1 is empty string or value_2 is empty string.

For example: if I build a the following function. My intention is to build map of first type (see above) by calling buildBsonObject("123","") and the second one by calling buildBsonObject("", "456").

```
func buildBsonObject (value_1 string, value_2 string) {    
    return bson.M {
             "$match" : bson.M{
                "xyz" : "abc",
              },
              "$id_1" : value_1, 
              "$id_2" : value_2,
        }
}
```

If I do the following (see function buildBsonObject), then when value_1 is empty string, my mongo aggregation query will not work since it will treat as id_1 being "", whereas I intended to just have id_2 in my bson object.

Any suggestions on how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
func buildBsonObject(value_1 string, value_2 string) bson.M {
  m := bson.M{
    "$match": bson.M{
        "xyz": "abc",
    },
  }
  if value_1 != "" {
    m["$id_1"] = value_1
  }
  if value_2 != "" {
    m["$id_2"] = value_2
  }
  return m
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/Z09GrQr5gl)

An alternative is to pass the key name to the function:

```
func buildBsonObject(k string, v string) bson.M {
  return bson.M{
    "$match": bson.M{
        "xyz": "abc",
    },
    k: v,
  }
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/G3XRK1fKfY)

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is what I also thought should work but I had a bug (before I posted it here), actually I have multiple levels of bson maps, where I made a mistake and I thought it wont work like that :(